# Loading csv to postgresql using copy from command

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to load data into postgresql from csv. During this process, I come across certain issue:-

here is my code:-

```
stmt1 = conPost.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int columnCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
                for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
                    if(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) == "varchar" || rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) == "text" || rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) == "char") {
                        header.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    }
                }
                if(header.isEmpty()) {
                    copyQuery="COPY "+this.tableName+"("+columns+") FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER '"+this.delimit+"' CSV HEADER";
                } else {
                    strListString = header.toString();
                    strListString = strListString.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
                    copyQuery="COPY "+this.tableName+"("+columns+") FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER '"+this.delimit+"' CSV HEADER FORCE NULL " + strListString;
                }
```

Previously, I come across issue that, NULL values in csv for varchar,text columns are as **""** . So, I used FORCE NULL option on varchar and text type columns so that it will insert **""** NULL only. Now it is working fine.

Now the new issue is:- if in my csv text data is like
**"Hi, "vignesh". How do you do"**
After loading into postgres:- it is like
**Hi, vignesh. How do you do**

I mean, suppose if inside the text data in csv contains double quotes, it is not inserting it as double quotes in postgres.

Is I'm missing something??? How can we overcome this??? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try to specify `QUOTE` in your copy statement? What is the text delimiter in your csv file (if some column value contains , / ; or CR/LF)?

Answer (score 0):

I would state that the problem is in your source string.

```
"Hi, "vignesh". How do you do"
```

Contains `"` also in the middle of the string, making it parsable incorrectly.

I would try to alter the string to be something similar to

```
"Hi, ""vignesh"". How do you do"
```

I tested the case with a file composed by

```
1,"Hi, ""vignesh"". How do you do"
```

And a table made of

```
create table testtable (id int, text varchar);
```

when executing the

```
copy testtable from 'data.csv' delimiter ',' CSV;
```

I end up with

```
 id |             text
----+------------------------------
  1 | Hi, "vignesh". How do you do
```

Comment: My csv contains lot of data. so I'm not intrested to do it manually, so how can we achieve that without checking and editing complete csv file